# AWS S3 Sync with JS/Node SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp

Amazon Web Services - Command Line Interface (AWS-CLI) has a [sync command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).  Unfortunately AWS CLI's `sync` method is a bit buggy.  I'd like to sync to S3 using a gulp build process and [Amazon's javascript/node SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html).

Unfortunately, the SDK doesn't seem to have a sync method, or does it?

What is the best way to sync whole directories in Node with AWS S3?

Comment: https://github.com/pgherveou/gulp-awspublish

Comment: Has anyone found out why aws-sdk doesn't offer a `sync` method? Here is the list of methods, and `sync` isn't in there: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Comment: You could use High Level Amazon S3 Client node-package,
it has a `sync` option:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Update:**

`aws s3 sync` is still only available with CLI. Most of the AWS SDKs still don't implement s3 sync. I found an **npm** library which does a decent job. Please checkout [s3-sync-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-sync-client). There are many alternatives in javascript but they have their limitations w.r.t. sync. This package overcomes almost all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI is more stable now. So, my solution:

```
gulp.task("sync-buckets", done => {
    let conf = loadConf();
    exec(`aws s3 sync --acl public-read bucket/www_static/ s3://${conf.BucketName}`, done);
});
```